# Integrating Azure pipeline with Gitlab (Continuous Integration)

Tags: asp.net, azure, continuous-integration, gitlab, azure-pipelines

Am trying to use Azure pipeline CI with my repository on Gitlab, I tried to embed a `yml` file to run the continuous integration but I couldn't.

When I used Github, the process was really easy and too direct, but for Gitlab I used the *Other Git* option.

[image]

But my builds I run them manually, how can I make them automatic so that when someone raise a Pull request a CI runs and checks if the build passes?

Is there a good guide for Gitlab Azure pipeline setup?

Answer (score 3):

If what you want is to using a `yml` file to run the CI from your Gitlab repository, we need to say, sorry, we does not support this feature until now. Our team is contributing to expand the service feature which can make more engineers and users conveniently.

Until now, if you choose **Other Git** to connect your repos of Gitlab, it will just be triggered automatically after the merge request **completed**. That's means after the pull request created, it is impossible to trigger the build in Azure Devops. So that it will not help you finish build verification before merge request completed.

In our official feature suggestion forum, there has an such [feature suggestion](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/462450/allow-using-yaml-build-pipelines-with-gitlab-repos.html) raised by other user. Just vote it and comment it there. Our PM and the product group review these ticket regularly, and considering take it as Roadmap if this feature be voted by many users. Hope you can help our Devops has more and more convenient feature.

In addition, here has an work around may help you achieve this: a third party application named [Zapier](https://zapier.com/apps/azure-devops/integrations/gitlab). There has an event **New merge request Event** for Gitlab, and for Azure Devops, you can choose Trigger a build.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Gitlab integrates natively with azure devops** on this interface.
Just go to the "other git" option and put the information like the image below

[image]

Comment: This will only work for Azure DevOps Classic pipelines

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you can not start with yaml with other git repository.

You may create an Azure devops repo by cloning from your project in Gitlab. Then you can start with "Azure Git Repo YAML"

Update:

For how to run your pipeline automatically, you can use CI triggers with some conditions. Here is a tutorial: [Build triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

Comment: So , how will the cloned project on Azure detect changes from gitlab repo ?

Comment: I did not find a setting for this in Azure DevOps. But, as the DevOps repos still uses git. You may add Azure repos as a mirror at your local, so that your changes will be push to it too. Here is a tutorial for this: https://www.opentechguides.com/how-to/article/git/177/git-sync-repos.html